# Google Chrome version 37 crash wordpress website since today - UPDATED

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome

But on Chrome 38 the website is okay, but on Google Chrome version 37 I see the website starting to appear then it crash (small crashed folder icon appears). This only do it on Chrome 37, both mac and pc, but nowhere else. That bug didn't exist before this morning...

**UPDATE : I finally found where it is bugging, in the footer.php codes, seems to be this line.**

```
` <div class="site-info">
<a href="http://www.example.com">My Site &copy; 2014</a>    | 
<a href="http://www.example.com/plan/">Site map</a> |  
<a href="http://www.example.com/support/">Support</a>   |   
<a href="http://www.myownexample.com" title="websites" target="_blank">Website by Me</a>
    </div><!-- .site-info --> `
```

When I remove this code bloc, the site is okay again.

Any idea of tho fix this bug, because I can't see where the code is wrong ?

Comment: Without more information we can't really help and since it only happens on v37 since today, I would guess it could be something you changed on the website.

Comment: If it was only this, lol. But I have updated every plugins and the WP system too. So since this morning (after I saw the crash) they are up to date. I also have rename the plugins folder in FTP for a quick test... nope, the site still crash on this Chrome v37.

Comment: Have you checked the site on multiple computers running Chrome 37? I still have 37 on my computer, so if you post a link, I can check to see if it's a Chrome issue, or an issue with just your computer.

Comment: Tested in 3 cities, on 8 computers and devices...

Comment: Update : only two of my websites have this problem above. They are both hosted on the same server, using the same theme 2012 + a different child each. Almost looks like it crashes arriving at the bottom of the page... or almost.

Comment: Updated, please read original question above.

Comment: Give us a functional test link, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this bug above... it is from the dark side of the force!

What I did was just retype the exact code (not copy-paste it), it is the **exact** same thing. Well, it doesnt crash Chome 37 and 38 on pc and mac. So weird. Case close. Thanks for the help above.

Answer (score 0):

`example.com` is a special DNS name that can cause problems with any number of networked software. It should **NEVER** make it out onto an actual site and may only be used for documentation purposes.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606, section 3.

Edit: Because this namespace is IANA reserved, you have no guarantee how any network software will handle it or to where any particular DNS resolver will resolve the name.  This means that behavior can easily differ between browsers.  Chrome *should* ignore it ... but it would be best to remove them from your HTML before you request them from a network location.

Comment: Stackoverflow asked me to write example dot com instead of mysite dot com. That was just for the code example above :-) Thanks for the note, i'll use something else next time.

Comment: Then I suggest for the future you make it clear that your post doesn't exactly represent your code ... otherwise, the rest of us will be stabbing wildly into the dark.